# How can I increase the value displayed to a Seven-segment display with increments based on the number of times a photocell's value is changed?

Tags: c++, arduino

So I've been working on an arduino project that is supposed to emulate a laser tripwire. A laser shines into a photoresistor, and each time the voltage input to the board is increased because of an absence of light, the board should display the `counter` variable to the seven segment display.

But for whatever reason, as soon as the resistor is activated, it executes the `counter = counter + 1` line an infinite number of times. I only want the counter to increase *once per activation*, as opposed to activating *while* the photoresistor has increased voltage.

Anyone here who can help?

```
#include "SevSeg.h"
SevSeg sevseg;

const int pResistor = A0;
//the photoresistor is connected to analog input pin A0

int count; //number of times voltage is increased
int value; //voltage reading of A0

void setup() {
  pinMode(pResistor, INPUT);

  byte numDigits = 1;
  byte digitPins[]={};
  byte segmentPins[]={6, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9};
  bool resistorsOnSegments = true;

  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE;
  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments);
  sevseg.setBrightness(90);

}

void loop() {
  value=analogRead(pResistor);
//here's where my problem starts
  while (count < 9){
    if (value>1022){
        //it should be noted that the photoresistor is preceded by a 100k Ω resistor, which 
        //explains the large value
      sevseg.setNumber(count);
    }
    else{
      count = count + 1;
      sevseg.setNumber(count);
    }

  }
//here's where my problem ends

  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
}
```

Comment: You need to add some memory. Have you learned about State Machines yet? Your machine has TWO STATES: "lit" and "unlit". Your loop function will have different behavior depending on which state you're in. If you're in the "lit" state, it will check if the photoresistor is unlit, and if so, do two things: 1. transition to "unlit", and 2. increment the counter. If in the "unlit" state, it will check if the photoresistor is lit, and if so, transition to the "lit" state. This way the number only increases on a transition from lit to unlit. Not every microsecond that it is unlit.

Comment: Look for the "State Change Example" in the Arduino IDE example codes.  It shows how to react once to a button push by remembering the last state in a variable.  You'll be doing something almost identical except instead of reading a button you are reading your sensor.